# Tailoring shapefile attributes with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, polygon, symbology, vector-layer

I'm adding a shapefile (as a vector layer) to QGIS with the snippet:

```py
def addere_urban(self):
    urbanareas = QgsVectorLayer('/home/ubuntu/SHAPEFILES/cb_2018_us_ua10_500k.shp', "Urban areas", "ogr")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(urbanareas)
```

The shapefile is widely available from, for example, https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html.
As the screenshot shows, it plots the urban areas as expected. Furthermore, I'm using my own CRS and the transformation for the shapefile looks good.

However, I'm having trouble tailoring the plot and would like to be able to make the following changes:

1 - Selection of the color to replace the (pinkish) color chosen by QGIS.

2 - Would it be possible to make the filling transparent (or no color) and plot only the boundaries?

3 - I thought that this file would also have the names of the major urban areas but that doesn't seem to be the case. Would I have to add another shapefile with these names? If so, any recommendations on where I might be able to find a good one?

This is part of a larger project so these tasks must be completed with PyQGIS.
Thanks
[image: Urban_areas_shapefile]

Comment: just style the layer interactively in QGIS and save the style as qml file. Then assign the qml: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.loadNamedStyle

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with these features (including qml files) so I'll have to read about them. I have several meetings but should be able to work on them this afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @thomas-b an alternative is to use a QML file, which allows to store all the representation configuration of a layer in QGIS.

For more information about QML:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/qgis_file_formats.html#qml-the-qgis-style-file-format

First you must assign the symbology to your layer in QGIS manually and then save it in a QML file, then you must use the generated QML file to assign the symbology to the layer using pyQGIS.

[image: set symbology]

[image: export qml file]

Here is an example that allows you to load only the symbology of a QML file ('It is important to note that the QML stores all the representation information of the layer and we only display the symbology').

**UPDATE**: I am updating the answer to use @thomas-b suggestion, which is more appropriate for this case and use less code.

```
qml_path = '/home/ai/Desktop/EXAMPLE/symbology.qml'
layer = QgsVectorLayer("/home/ai/Desktop/EXAMPLE/cb_2018_us_aiannh_500k.shp", "cb_2018_us_aiannh_500k", "ogr")

layer.loadNamedStyle(qml_path)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

For this example I used the following data: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_aiannh_500k.zip

And the following QML: https://gist.github.com/lacardonap/4bc14aa4cdb41f988d8b5955ab56a6ee

Once the qml symbology is loaded, the result is as follows:

[image: Applied symbology]

**Note**: the following video shows how to save symbology in qml format

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2N5ZyFlbqSQ

Comment: In your "save layer style" dialog only the symbology is checked, so It should be enough just to load the qml with loadNamedStyle as you did not save anything more than the symbology.